# how to break long enum list in swagger file into multiple lines

Tags: swagger-2.0

what is the correct way to break a very long list of enum values in the swagger 2.0 file?
I have a parameter with a very long list of enum values, spanning more than 80 character line, which decreases the code readability and maintainability. is there a way to break them down into multiple lines?

```
swagger: "2.0"
.
.
.
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: meta
          description: indicates the meta data type being requested
          type: string
          enum: [very, long, list, of, enum, values]
          required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is possible by defining multiple array like below

```
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: meta
          description: indicates the meta data type being requested
          type: string
          enum: 
            - long, list, of, enum, values
            - another, long, list, of, enum, values
          required: true
```